# Conditional Statement with Global Variable Issue

Tags: expressionengine

I've created a global variable in Expression Engine to be able to switch to a site I am testing.  But it is not working in an if statement.

```
{if test-mode == "true"}hello world{/if}
```

EE doesn't show the "hello world" text.  If I do this:

```
{test-mode}
```

It shows "true".  I can't figure out why it's not working...

Comment: I know nothing about Expression Engine, but does not having quotes around "true" help?

Answer (score 0):

This is a parse order issue.

In [the documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html), notice that conditionals are processed at steps 14 and 19 but global user variables are not processed until step 23.

Some work around options for this would be:

- Use an embed
- Use a Snippet
- Move the variable into PHP
- Use [Low Variables](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables) (third party add-on)

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a parse order issue (one of the major headaches of EE developers)

To get around this move test-mode and it's value from global variables to snippets. These are parsed earlier.

I've tested this and it works.

As a global variable - doesn't work:

```
{if test_mode == "true"}Hello world{/if}
```

As a snippet - works!

```
{if test_mode_snippet == "true"}Hello world snippet{/if}
```

To read more on parse order have a look at [***this link***](http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf) from Low (of Low Variables). Although I'm not sure of the accuracy as Snippets and Global Variables are classed as same.

It may also have something to do with parsing order of simple and complex conditionals. [***Read more here***](http://derekallard.com/blog/post/simple-vs-complex-conditionals-in-expressionengine-templates?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter)